# Unity LowLevel Touch Screen Detect android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was Working on a new application on unity and i wanted to make the perfamonce good for phones so what i did is i killed the playerloop that's mean i switched to the lowlevel unsing unityengine.lowlevel (playerloop) but the problem is i can't detect any touches i tried everything :

1. button click (normal) - dosn't worked
2. event systems - dosn't worked
3. addlistener button - dosn't worked
4. mouse click on the update - dosn't worked

so i read some unity articles and everything in stackoverflow and i didn't find anything .
will i killed the playerloop because a developer named "Jon Manning" sad sow and he explained how to detect touches on iphone and he did say that detect touches on android is possible but he didn't say how you can see the video here to better understand : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7CZyqHGKXw&t=1812s

so if anuone can help i will be very greatfull

Comment: Please rephrase your question and sentences to make it more understandable. Also please add any source code if available.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have created an Android app before, and the easiest way to detect touches on Android phones are with these functions:

```
private void OnMouseDrag() { // called every frame the user has their finger held down while touching the collider or GUI element }

private void OnMouseDown() { // called when the user presses the collider with their finger }
```

They work perfectly for single-touch applications, if you want multi-touch capability there are other methods you can use.

The only caveat is that these functions are only called when the user's finger touches the collider, so every object you want to have interacted with must have a collider attached, along with this script.

There are also other `OnMouse` functions which you can look up on the Unity Docs, if you want more control.

Comment: Will This Was Good Idea But It's Not Working at The LowLevel. anyway i talked to someone and he told me that there is no way to detect touch in unity in the lowlevel unless you used java or c++ plegun for detecting touches. So do you know how I can made plegun detect touches in unity using android studio or eclips ? Will I know how to create plugin and call him from unity but i don't know how to make the plugin detect touches on unity

Answer (score 0):

I don't Really understand Why unity realised the UnityEngine.lowlevel if there is no way to keep using the app or the game ones you kill the playerloop ,Will i know that it work on ios but What about android i think android is really important than ios because there is like 7% of the world using ios and the rest using android ,Will i know that the propably 7% are reach but i thnik that is not good reason

I will be using android studio and java for my app , and i hope unity team will do something about that and if anyone searching how to wake up from the lowlevel if you're not building for ios don't bother you're self go create plugin if possible or just don't use the low level and of course google play will not give you a nice number of downloads because of the perfamonce and the battery , unity is only for games stick with that i already made a lot of apps non of them got more than 10k downloads because of the perfamonce and the battery